# How to make custom border bottom for my hero section

Tags: html, css, svg, frontend, background-image

I want to creat the hero section showed in the following picture :

[image: My website design]

But the problem is that i 't know how to add the border on the bottom surrounded with the red color, is it possible to make them with css property or how ?

I tried to cut that portion and added it as div background but the problem is that it is little bit hard to make it responsive and it dosen't look good.

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, ***[search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=css+frayed+edge+site:stackoverflow.com)***; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: You can have two divs, one at top and at bottom and use CSS to add as a background image.